# Get newline in a random encoding

Tags: c#, text, encoding

I am sending some email to people in various cultures. The data comes from a file in the appropriate encoding. However, I need to read the first few lines to process them (get the subject etc.)
So I do:

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename, encoding);
 ... read first few lines up to blank...
 lines = String.Join(newline, lines.skip(lineNum));
```

However, I don't know what I should do to get the appropriate value of newline. It is different for each encoding, and I can't use Environment.NewLine because I need the newline for the specific encoding of the email recipient, not the encoding of the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're still dealing with *text*, so you don't need to worry about encodings (conversions to/from binary representations of character data). What you *do* need to potentially worry about is different representations of "new line" *in terms of characters*.

It's not clear what you're using to send the mail eventually - I expect whatever you use may well sort everything out for you anyway. However, [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) defines lines as being separated with CRLF ("\r\n") so I'd use that.

Of course if you're *also* sending an HTML version of the text, that'll contain HTML tags for line/paragraph separation anyway.

Comment: Great point. '\n' is a character not an encoding. There is quite a stack from font->glyph->character->code->encoding, it is hard to keep track!! For anyone who is reading in the future, I just joined with \n and everything was good (RFC822 was handled by the underlying email infrastructure I am using.)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read it line by line so that you don't care much about the encoding issue:

```
  while ((line = File.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
      if (line != String.Empty)
         lines += line + Environment.NewLine;
  }
```